# Does ALLOWED_HOSTS use get_host()?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-middleware

I'm slightly confused when it comes to how django is using the tuple in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to validate host. Does it use a `get_host()` call or does it use `request.META`?

The Django documentation indicates the following with regards to [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts):

> This validation only applies via `get_host()`; if your code accesses the `Host` header directly from `request.META` you are bypassing this security protection.

If I create middleware that uses `get_host()` to get the host and compare it to a list of approved host names and pass the user `404` if the domain isn't in the list, I assume this would essentially be replicating the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` functionality?

I ask this question because I do, in fact need to write middleware to replace `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. The list of approved hosts grows over time as more users sign up. As a result, I the tuple that I'm validating against is dynamic and thus, I can't use the default `ALLOWED_HOSTS` config in Django.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the implementation of [`get_host`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/http/request/#HttpRequest.get_host)? It's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Nope. I'm just wondering if the host validation that django does using ALLOWED_HOSTS makes use of the get_host() method.

Answer (score 3):

`ALLOWED_HOSTS` doesn't use anything, it's just a list. It's the other way around: `get_host()` uses `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to validate the value of the `Host` header. The documentation you linked to says this explicitly:

> If the `Host` header (or `X-Forwarded-Host` if `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` is enabled) does not match any value in this list, the **`django.http.HttpRequest.get_host()`** method will raise `SuspiciousOperation`.

If you want to replace this validation with your own, just use `*` for `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. Since any host will pass validation in that case, it doesn't matter if you use `get_host()` or access the headers directly.